# Retaining dropdown values in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a dropdown in my ASP.NET Core MVC application

```
<div class=" form-group">
    <div class="bisformdynamiclabel"></div>
    <select class="form-control" asp-for="BIS232Request.JSONData.RequestingOrg.HeadquartersCountry" id="HeadquartersCountry"></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="BIS232Request.JSONData.RequestingOrg.HeadquartersCountry" class="alert-danger"></span>
</div>
```

I am trying to retain the dropdown value after the submit NOT after the reload. Of course I can use session and the local storage; however, it will retain the value after the submit AND page refresh. I would like to retain the value JUST for the submit

Is there an easy and efficient way to achieve it in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Comment: What do you mean for the submit? It's not really clear what doesn't work

Comment: Clicking the Submit button

Comment: So... what happens? The select clears itself? You don't receive the data in the controller? Please add more details

Comment: The selected value in a dropdown does NOT retain (as I explained in the description)

I goes back to the top value of a dropdown that shows when the page first loads

Comment: Please post a [mcve] (you can use dotnetfiddle.net for help with making it reproducible), we cannot help you with so little details

Comment: Your question is not at all clear.

Comment: Sorry, all I meant is to keep the value of a dropdown after the reload triggered by a submit button. I found a solution

Comment: Your `<select>` makes no sense, and I can only assume `HeadquartersCountry` is a collection. A `<select>` binds to and post back a simple value, and your model needs both a property to bind to (say `int` or `string` and a collection property (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`) for the options. Suggest you read [ASP.NET Core MVC Select Tag Helper](https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/05/18/mvc6-select-tag-helper.aspx) to understand how to use the TagHelper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did overthink it and found a simple solution

In the submit button click event I did

```
sessionStorage.setItem("SetHeadquartersCountryItem", $('#HeadquartersCountry').val());
```

In the load event I did

```
var selItem = sessionStorage.getItem("SetHeadquartersCountryItem");
$('#HeadquartersCountry').val(selItem);
sessionStorage.removeItem("SetHeadquartersCountryItem");
```